# A change to Friedmann's 2nd equation

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion

$$\tag{1}\frac{\ddot a}{a}=-\frac{4\pi G}{3}\left(\rho + \frac{3p}{c^2}\right)+\frac{\Lambda c^2}{3}$$

$$\tag{2}\frac{\ddot a}{a}=+\frac{4\pi G}{3}\left(\rho + \frac{3p}{c^2}\right)+\frac{\Lambda c^2}{3}$$

If Friedmann's equation $(1)$ states,  as pressure goes up in the system mass increases its attractive force and collapses inward, would  equation $(2)$ state that a pressure will build inside the system and  the expansion of the system will accelerate and will be resisted by an outside force? Meant to put a - in front of the Cosmological Constant.

Comment: Please, use the LaTeX commands to write your equations instead of posting a large picture on its side!

Comment: Sorry Cham. I'm a very adult student. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: you can see this: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/804/

Comment: @JasonVerreault, it is then a right place and time to learn some LaTeX basics.  Edit your question by using \$\$\tag{number}equation\$\$, and use some simple commands to write your equations inside the dollar signs.  It's easy, it's fun, and extremely usefull!

Comment: I'll edit your question to show you how to add a numbered equation with a fraction.  Edit it to make your question more precise.

Comment: One [meta Q&A about beginners using MathJax](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10905/170832).

Comment: What do you mean by "false equation to be edited" ? I want to help but its really unclear what you are asking ? You are talking about equation (1) but you have a picture and a latex that both showns as "(1)". Can you edit your question please

Comment: Thank you, Cham

Answer (score 1):

First we should remember that, $P = w\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is the energy density.

> as pressure goes up in the system mass increases its attractive force and collapses inward,

Mass does not increase its attractive force as P increases. We know that  $w = 0$ for matter. This means that there is no exerted pressure by the non-relativistic matter

An increase in the P can only mean that the energy density of radiation or dark energy is increasing.

Let's re-write the acceleration equation in this form

$$\frac{\ddot a}{a}=-\frac{4\pi G}{3c^2}\sum_i^3(\epsilon_i + 3w\epsilon_i)$$

$$\frac{\ddot a}{a}=-\frac{4\pi G}{3c^2}\sum_i^3\epsilon_i(1 + 3w)$$

such that $i=1$ is radiation, $i=2$ is baryonic matter and $i=3$ is $\Lambda$

$$\frac{\ddot a}{a}=-\frac{4\pi G}{3c^2}(\epsilon_m + 2\epsilon_r - 2\epsilon_{\Lambda}) $$

So when you increase the matter or radiation energy density acceleration of the universe slows down. And when you increase the dark energy density, you would increase the acceleration of the universe

Now, when you put "+" in front of the acceleration equation you get.

$$\frac{\ddot a}{a}=+\frac{4\pi G}{3c^2}(\epsilon_m + 2\epsilon_r - 2\epsilon_{\Lambda}) $$

In this type of universe increasing the matter or radiation energy density would increase the acceleration of the universe. And increasing the dark energy density would decrease the acceleration of the universe.